# How to stop animation on the start position / frame zero

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I tried to stop the animation objects with a button, I want to when it stops, the object is located at the starting position. 
For example I have a cube with animated moving position. when the stop button is pressed, the cube back to its original position.

Answer (score 0):

When no animations are playing, Unity does not change the object's position at all - so stopping it will not reset the position for you. It will just not move it any *more.*

If you want to return the object to the configuration it was in before you started playing your animation, you have to do it yourself. Your options are:

- Make the start position be set by an animation as well. That way you can just play *that* animation after the other one has finished.
- Make the animation you're playing return the object to its start position at the end - i.e. have the last frame of the animation be back at the object's start position.
- Write code that captures and restores the object's position, by saving the values of transform.position/transform.rotation and then setting them again when the animation has finished.

Comment: I created two buttons, the play button and stop button .. when the marker is detected, I make the animation play automatically .. but why when i press the stop button object is not returned to the starting position?
What should I do? I am still confused with your explanation ..
Can you give me an example?